# How to create a tf.data.Dataset from a DataFrame where every entry of one column is a fixed-length Numpy array or list?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

How to create a tf.data.Dataset from a DataFrame where every entry of one column is a fixed-length Numpy array or list?

I am getting this error,
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,np.array([3,4])], [4,5,np.array([6,7])]], columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(df))

Answer (score 0):

For mixed data types, use Dataset.from_generator:

```
def iter_to_gen(it):
    def f():
        for x in it:
            yield x
    return f


ds = Dataset.from_generator( iter_to_gen(map(tuple, df.values)),  (tf.int32, tf.int32, tf.int32))
print(list(ds.as_numpy_iterator()))
```

which yields:

```
[(1, 2, array([3, 4], dtype=int32)), (4, 5, array([6, 7], dtype=int32))]
```